# Google Analytics says I don't have admin access to migrate to google analytics 4 even though I'm admin

Tags: google-analytics, admin, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to migrate my website "bloomfieldnetworks.com" to google analytics 4. When I go on google it's not giving me access, saying I don't have access. When I look at property, it says I have admin access and I was also granted admin access a while back. The person that gave me admin access is also having trouble as well. They said it's giving them the same thing, of not have admin access to this website.

I went on google analytics and clicked finish google analytics 4. it says I don't have admin access. I asked the owner of the website to try to do it himself because he also has admin access and it's telling him he doesn't have admin access as well. When I go on Admin - property admin access it says I am an admin and so is he but neither of us can continue doing the google analytics 4 because we don't have "admin access"